# TextureView functionality in Android pre-4.0?

Tags: android, surfaceview, viewflipper

I would like to know is there any way that I could get similar functionality to that of TextureView in the Android 2.2 or 2.33 environment? Specifically I am looking for a way to place a dynamic view (like SurfaceView) inside a ViewFlipper (as can be done with a TextureView). Any and all help with regard to this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So far I don't think that this is possible. Nothing I can find and nothing in the support library.